# Android SplashScreen API is not compatible with AppCompatActivity and Material

Tags: android, android-activity, material-design, appcompatactivity, android-splashscreen

Seems that [Android Splash Screen API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/window/SplashScreen) is not compatible with AppCompatActivity and Material Theme. OK, this as said in link, it speaks only about Activity-class not AppCompatActivity-class, but I did not realize that restriction and used days to implement SpashScreen with this API, because it seems to be very simple and easy to use, but reality was for far of that.

Igor Escodro tell us basics about [Implementing Core Splashscreen API](https://proandroiddev.com/implementing-core-splashscreen-api-e62f0e690f74) which is not told is Android guide. You must define Spash Screen theme and then you normal app normal theme, but unfortunately he does not mention, that material themes are not supported even though they work fine with fragments and AppCompat classes. And unfortunately they don't mention that you can't use AppCompatActivity with Material theme with material any more, because material theme is not set to activity, but standard theme even though "postSplashScreenTheme" is properly set in splash screen theme.

It is impossible for me or most others app developers change AppCompatActivity to Activity, because many requirements require AppCompatActivity and Activity is not compatible. And we wan't that our apps loaded to all phones, not only to the latest Android phones and AppCompatActivity os tool to do that.

After struggling days with SplashScreen API I am wondering what is happening with Google's Android developing, why they publish APIs that is not usable with old apps and old phones at all. Why documentation is so poor.

If you can advice me how to make my app with AppCompatActivitys, Fragments and Material Theme to work will be very happy, I promise.

Comment: Unclear if you've seen: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate

Comment: Use  the compat one https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I studied more. Seems that as documentations says in Themes

```
<style name="Theme.MySplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
  <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher_round</item>
  <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyTheme.Material</item>  
</style>
```

is not enough. You must add in manifest for every activity, that they use your material theme (if they use as my app does), as

```
    <activity
        android:name="..."
        ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme.Material"
        >
    </activity>
```

for every activity using Material Theme. After that app works normally.